# Custom styling for form label

Tags: validation, ionic-framework, ionic3

Upon submitting the form and receive callback from the API, if the input has any error, I would like to make the label text color become red, if no error it will become green.

1. I am familiar with jQuery way e.g. `$('#labelUsername').addClass('danger');` but how to do it in ionic 3?
2. What is the proper way of putting my own custom styling?
3. In future I might also add icon (append) to the label if that is possible?

**CSS**

```
.danger {
   color:red;
}

.success {
   color:green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label id="labelCustomer">Customer</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="customer" name="customer" type="text" text-right></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**TS**

```
let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
options: any = { formValue },
url: any = "[urlhere]";

this.http.post(url, options, headers)
.subscribe((data: any) => {

  if(data.error){
    // $('#labelCustomer').addClass('danger'); <-- something like this
  }
},
(error: any) => {
console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code you can use to implement the same

```
<ion-badge [ngClass]="changecolor">Customer</ion-badge>
```

In component.ts file define changecolor variable like :

```js
let headers: any = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }),
options: any = { formValue },
url: any = "[urlhere]";

this.http.post(url, options, headers)
.subscribe((data: any) => {

  if(data.error){
    //define class name
    this.changecolor = "danger"
  }else{
    this.changecolor = "success"
  }
},
(error: any) => {
console.log(error);
});
```

put below css in scss file

```css
page-login {
  .danger {
    color:red;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

  .success {
    color:green;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
}
```